# Javascript/jQuery - replace last occurence of a word in a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a string that ends with a fixed word - `Button`. Now I need to replace that word with `''`. How can I do it? Also, if my string is something like `ButtonButton` or similar, I need to cut out only last `Button`.

Comment: Replace with `''`? I'm pretty sure that's called *removing* `:-P`

Comment: Fixed length – no need for RegEx then. substr/substring will do just fine.

Answer (score 12):

```
var original = 'ButtonButton';
var newString = original.replace(/Button$/, '');
// "Button"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = "you string with button";
var newstring = str.replace(/button$/i, '');
```

Read about [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have to check, if it really ends with `Button`, just remove the last 6 letters:

```
var str = "ButtonButton"; 
str = str.substr(0,str.length-6); 
console.log(str); //"Button"
```